# Cost Averaging Negative Quantities Within A Group

Tags: mysql

I have read through many SO posts about generating a cost average for inventory, but how would you handle a situation where there are negative values in the quantity field?

I understand that with the following logic, mysql doesn't take the order of results into consideration.  It does not know that prior to the last 2000 quantity entry for apples, the total quantity was 0 making the cost basis for the final 2000 apples '11.33'.

Is there a way to approach this problem in a single query, or is a step function in order?

```
SELECT 

    fruit,
    SUM(quantity) as quantity,
    SUM(quantity*price)/SUM(quantity)

FROM products 
GROUP BY fruit");
```

Here is a sample table of products -

```
 +--------+----------+---------+
 | id | fruit  | quantity | price   |
 +----+--------+----------+---------+
 |  1 | grapes |     2000 | 13.0900 |
 |  2 | apples |     1000 | 10.8900 |
 |  3 | grapes |      100 | 12.6000 |
 |  4 | grapes |      100 | 12.6800 |
 |  5 | apples |    -1000 | 11.2800 |
 |  6 | grapes |     2200 | 12.4300 |
 |  7 | grapes |    -4400 | 12.4300 |
 |  8 | apples |     2000 | 11.3300 |
 |  9 | apples |    -2000 | 11.3200 |
 | 10 | apples |     2000 | 11.3300 |
 +----+--------+----------+---------+
```

The price column shows the transaction price.  There are buys and sells in the same column (quantity), as demonstrated by the negative values.

The output should be one line per fruit with the quantity, and average price.  In this example the return should include apples at '11.33', however I'm showing '11.15' because of the cancelled out stock prices.

```
 +--------+----------+---------+
 | fruit  | quantity | price   |
 +--------+----------+---------+
 | grapes |        0 | 00.0000 |
 | apples |     2000 | 11.3300 |
 +--------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: what is your desire output for that data?

Comment: Your sample doesnt match your desire result..  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c60e/9 as you can see apples price is `11.00`

Comment: You are correct.  If it did, I would not need SO :)

Comment: I tought your problem was the null, then you need to explain the formula on why should be `11.33` or `11.15` not sure what value you want

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The OP wants to *completely remove* from the average calculation all rows with a total of quantity equal to 0.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I dont think so, because his result show `quantity = 0`  also the main problem is normal average wont result in `11.33` with that data return will be `11` so there is a different sum/avg rule there somewhere

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `quantity=0` for grapes because the total `quantity` sums up to 0. For `'apples'` the only row left, after filtering out all other rows whose quantity sums up to 0, is the last one. Hence, average price is `11.3300` for apples.

Comment: Giorgos Betsos is right.  Rows that are cancelled out by negative quantities after them should not be affecting the outstanding quantities.  If you have an apple for $1, another apple for $5, sold a previous apple for $3 (cost average), the remaining apple should display a price of $3.  My query works for this.  Problem comes into play when you sell both apples and purchase a third for $10.  The output should just show 1 apple at $10, not taking the previous price points into consideration.  There may be no way to do this in a single query...

Comment: I mean his original query say `HAVING SUM(quantity) != 0` that will remove the `grapes  = 0` row. But hey if you have idea what the problem is post one answer, because im cluless :(

Comment: That looks like you need some variables to make cumulative sum, and yes that can be made with a query. Will wait for Betsos or for a more detail example.

Comment: And for that you need provide one `ID` or `DATE` column so we can order the transactions

Comment: Ok, sounds good.  I've included an id column.  How do you use variables to make a cumulative sum?  Would you just zero out the cumulative price each time the total quantity crosses 0 and keep a counter for how many quantity equals the price that zeros out as well?

Comment: Yes, but im still dont understand your rules.

Comment: It's pretty simple.  The purpose of the query is to get the current price of fruit.  The current price of fruit is based on stock at hand, and it should be a weighted average of the individual entries' price.  SUM(price * quantity)/SUM(quantity).  Once the quantities cancel out and cross zero, all prices up to that point are worthless and should not effect the weighted average because their quantities are equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your values are just sell / buy and you want the total of the volumn of transactions. Now if you want something with inventary stocks you need provide a better explanation of the formula.

Use `IF` expresion to change to the correct value

```
SELECT     
    fruit,
    SUM( IF(quantity>0, quantity, -quantity) ) as quantity,
    SUM( IF(quantity>0, quantity, -quantity) * price) 
     / SUM( IF(quantity>0, quantity, -quantity) )

FROM products 
GROUP BY fruit
HAVING SUM(quantity) != 0
ORDER BY fruit ASC");
```

Comment: I've updated the question with an output table.  Unfortunately your answer wouldn't do anything because I already have the negative quantity values in the table.  The problem is more of an order of operations thing.  Look at the output values and it should clear things up.

Comment: I see, but now I need more information. Looks like is a step by step calculation? Can you elaborate about the process?

Comment: It is step by step.  If I were to do this in a script, I would loop through each fruit -> within each fruit loop through each row of result -> add / subtract the quantity -> calculate the average price on the final outstanding quantity.  If there is only 2000 apples left in a single row and the price is 11.33, then the price for 2000 apples should be 11.33.  If the last 2000 quantity would be split across 2 rows at 1000 @ 5.00 and 1000 @ 10.00, the price should be 7.50.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Not at all, sorry. You have to work litle hard to explain your problem. I can help you translate that to sql, but you are the one how need explain the problem for someone outside your field. Maybe try case by case... one fruit, one sell ... then two sells... then two sell and one buys. then two and two.

Comment: I am sure I could do this. I know about 5 people that answer these types of questions currently. The problem is, the back and forth with the OP on this is going to be 30 min to 90 min of someone's life. It is going to go the way of nested `cursors` or complex variables.